# Bash Alias Not Found Error

Tags: bash, alias

I have the following command that I am trying to put into a bash alias.  The command by itself works fine, but when I try to alias it, I am getting the following errors:

The Command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "$(find "{}" -type f | wc -l)" {}' \; | sort -nr
```

The Alias

```
alias csfiles='find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "$(find "{}" -type f | wc -l)" {}' \; | sort -nr'
```

The Error:

```
-sh: alias 0: not found
-sh: alias {} \; | sort nr: not found
```

I think this means I am not using quotes right but I am having trouble determining the correct combo.  Help?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an alias use a function. Also,I wouldn't use find's placeholder- `{}` as a parameter in the inline script.

```
csfiles () {
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'for dir
do
        echo "$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l)" "$dir"
done' sh {} + | sort -nr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This command should work:

```
alias csfiles='find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c `echo "$(find "{}" -type f | wc -l)" {}` \; | sort -nr'
```

basically for the echo command you need to change from ' to `

Comment: On first glance that doesn’t appear to be equivalent, won't that fork and return the result in place rather than being an argument to the command? (Indent with 4 spaces for code formatting, otherwise the command will be parsed for formatting characters, see the preview when composing your post.)